# How to run cuda-gdb in windows? Can I use cygwin for it?

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I want to debug my application using cuda-gdb in windows. Is it possible to run cuda-gdb in windows? Will cygwin help to do it?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That seems like a pretty good answer to me, if you could care to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cuda-gdb` is not officially supported for or intended for usage in a windows environment.  From [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html#introduction):

> This document introduces CUDA-GDB, the NVIDIA® CUDA® debugger for Linux and Mac OS.

cygwin is not an officially supported environment for running any of the CUDA linux tools on windows.

The recommended debugger for windows applications is [NSIGHT Visual Studio Edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition), which will be automatically installed by the CUDA 7.5 installer for windows, assuming a compatible version of visual studio is found.

For supported configurations, refer to the [CUDA 7.5 windows installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#abstract).